# How should I export to zip file in Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I dont know how should i export to zip file my android project. i am using 3.0.1 ide which is latest version.Is there this option in android studio? some people say android studio doesnt have gthis option

Answer (score 1):

From the main menu, choose File > Export to Zip File.

Comment: while doing it my project becomes 200-300 kb is it normal?

Comment: @user245548: I do not know what you mean, sorry.

Comment: i mean when i use that way export to zip file my 50 mb project becomes 200-300 kb

Comment: @user245548: I do not know how you are measuring either of your sizes. But the ZIP file does not contain the compiled results of your project, such as the contents of the `build/` directories. Those get very large. Plus, the ZIP file has compression.

Comment: If you are concerned that the ZIP doesn't contain "everything", open it with a ZIP tool / archive tool and see what files are there.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the .idea and .gradle folders (not .gradle files), the size of the compressed folder will be smaller than the zip Android studio creates for you.